# Can you make a Conditional Statement to use, or not use, some JavaScript depending on Viewport Size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, conditional-statements

I wonder if anyone can work this **HTML, CSS, Javascript** puzzle out?

I'm using an **@media viewport CSS declaration** to detect mobile screen sizes, which **minifies** my website **for mobile visitors**, purely using CSS which is nice as I only have 1 website to update, not 2. So far so good... :)

However, in my HTML there's a line of code referencing a Javascrit file that makes this really nice **'soft scrolling'** effect on the main navigational ul li a links (eg ).

This all works fine on the **normal version** of the site, but for some unknown reason it **stops** the navigation working altogether on the **minified version** of the site. If I delete this link to the *js/softscroll.js* file, then the links on the minified site work fine & I'm OK about loosing this effect on the mini version, but then... the main sites navigation stops! :< I have to have this effect for the main site btw.

**So, my question is...**

...Is there a way to make some kind of **conditional statement**, in either HTML or JavaScript (JS I imagine!), that will tell browser to only use that JavaScript (js/softscroll.js) ...IF ... the visitor is ONLY viewing the normal site, and... obviously ignore the js/softscroll.js file IF the mobile version of the site is being accessed?

Whoaw! I hope you understand what the hell I'm going on about!? Ha! Your probably wondering what I'm trying to achieve here, or why I'm so into this javascript effect? Long story, but let's just say I'm making one of those crazy side scrolling websites and it's vital! :0)

So yeh? any help welcome! Thanks for your time!

Comment: can do without the bolds. Real eye catching!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can conditionally load a script with jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
if(mainsite) $.getScript('js/softscroll.js');
```

**UPDATE**

First, when you need Javascript, you REALLY need jQuery. Best to download it and put it on your site - http://jquery.org

But here's a way that might work now:

in the head section of your app:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

Next, you need a way to know if your site is being accessed by a mobile device or not:

```
<script>
    var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
    var mobile = platform.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android)/);
```

Then, you need to conditionally load your special script:

```
    if(!mobile) $.getScript('js/softscroll.js');
</script>
```

Those six lines of code, added to the head section of your site, will probably do for now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
    var mobile = platform.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android)/);
    if(!mobile) $.getScript('js/softscroll.js');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Matt! I think I understand the theory of your example, but I only know CSS not Javascript, so I'm still a bit lost on how to use your example, specifically the (mainsite) bit? it would be more like if(mobile.css)? is that possible? And are you sure this would work with just the one website with two CSS versions of it (normal.css and mobile.css?)

Comment: Updated to show how to use jQuery and how to determine if the site is mobile. Note that the method for mobile is a reliable way, but there's currently no guaranteed way to detect if a browser is definitely mobile, as modern browsers can emulate various devices.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks so much for your time on this, I really appreciate this. SUre it will help others too. I get this, nice and clear, but only thing is that is the wrong way around, what I mean is that by default the js/softscroll.js script is already working on the main site, so how could I adapt your code so that it STOPS js/softscroll.js from running - if it detects (!mobile), as it messes with the mobile site? Thanks again! ;-)

Comment: Let's say for example I have a different scroll effect for the mobile (mobilescroll.js) and a softscroll.js for the normal site. Could I just add an 'else' statement to your code like this;

<script>
    var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();
    var mobile = platform.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android)/);
    if(!mobile) $.getScript('js/mobilescroll.js');
    else $.getScript('js/softscroll.js'); 
</script>

Comment: That's what it does - stops it from running - the ! in front on mobile, i.e. if (!mobile) means NOT - if NOT mobile then load the script. And yes, if !(mobile) { get script } else {get mobile script}

Answer (score 1):

you can use mediaqueries.js  http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/
i prefer adapt.js https://github.com/nathansmith/adapt

Comment: Thanks Albert, but these examples seem to choose and serve CSS, whereas I need something that can choose and serve A javaScript file, or not as the case may be?

Comment: the functionality you are seeking are in both. i'm looking at adapt.min.js now...  http://adapt.960.gs/assets/js/adapt.min.js  see where the link element is being created? you could easily swap that out for the desired script

Answer (score 0):

As Matt H (+1) correctly pointed out, you can conditionally load a script using JS.

Also, you can see an article which deals with Viewport size [here](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm not experienced with JS, could you please give me an example of how to write a conditional javascript load function, in this scenario?